# remote access mongodb on openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I can't access remotely to my mongodb on openshift.

I tried this configuration:

mongodb.conf

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0  or bind_ip = 127.9.218.2
port = 27017
auth = true
```

Here you have the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you port forward,  use 127.0.0.1:27017 to connect.

Comment: This is not working and i can't understood why i use my localhost

Comment: Did you put in your password? Plus you do t need to change the mongodb.conf file.

Comment: my connection url  mongodb://admin:GddZCz4G3xfB@127.9.218.2:27017/admin

Comment: Look at my answer. use 127.0.0.1:27017.  That is being port forwarded to the correct port on Openshift.

Comment: Thansk for attetion and interesting yes I've tried  this 127.0.0.1:27017 and not working  send global ip because  if you want to check yourself

Comment: What mongodb client are you using?  I use mongovue and always connect this way.  If fact, i'm connected to my mongodb database right now.

Comment: I using robomogo . Yes you are right mongovue and local ip working thank you so much. I want to buy you a coffee   ☕☕☕